# Why is my princomp plot empty despite returning no errors?

Tags: r, plot, pca

Princomp has been used to summarise a large data set, the summary, screeplot and loadings are all functional and all of the code has been repeated from an earlier pca. The code for the plot is also very similar and when it is run, no error is returned but the plot is completely empty.

This happened initially with the original code but the problem seemed to be resolved by running princomp and summary again, this solution has not worked this time.

```
Plot_chars.abio.pca <-princomp(Plot_chars_standardised[,4:12]) 
summary(Plot_chars.abio.pca)

Plot_chars.abio.pca$loadings

screeplot(Plot_chars.abio.pca, type="lines")


Plot_chars.abio.pca.var <- Plot_chars.all.pca$sdev^2
Plot_chars.abio.pca.var[1:5]

plot(Plot_chars.abio.pca$x[,1], Plot_chars.abio.pca$x[,2],
bty = "n",
pch = Plot_chars$DomSpec -20,
cex =0.5,
col= Plot_chars$DomSpec -10, 
xlim = c(-2,6),
ylim = c(-2,6),
xlab = "PCA1",
ylab = "PCA2")
```

I was expecting the PC1 & PC2 points plotted but nothing appears

Answer (score 0):

The result from `princomp` does not contain a column named `x`. For the scores plot use `Plot_chars.abio.pca$scores[, 1]` for PC1 and `Plot_chars.abio.pca$scores[, 2]`. For the loadings plot use `Plot_chars.abio.pca$loadings[, 1]` for the loadings in PC1 and `Plot_chars.abio.pca$loadings[, 2]` for the loadings in PC2.

Your example:

```
plot(Plot_chars.abio.pca$scores[,1], Plot_chars.abio.pca$scores[,2],
bty = "n",
pch = Plot_chars$DomSpec -20,
cex =0.5,
col= Plot_chars$DomSpec -10, 
xlim = c(-2,6),
ylim = c(-2,6),
xlab = "PCA1",
ylab = "PCA2")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was following some class instructions which told me to include x. That has worked perfectly.